Xcode: Open files in new Tabs instead of new Windows
When I open a new file in Xcode, e.g. from Finder (see the screenshot below) or using the "Xcode > File > Open" menu item, the file is opened in a new Xcode window. Is it possible to tell Xcode to always open files in new tabs instead?

